# Finding the datasets in paper "Hierarchical Attention Networks for Document Classification"

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, imdb

I'm an AI research trainee and trying to re-implement the model mentioned in the paper "Hierarchical Attention Networks for Document Classification" on the same datasets they used for their research (as shown in the picture).

However, I've been finding these materials to no avails. Can someone tell me about a website/database that may contain these academic resources.

Can I contact the paper authors and request the datasets?
Thank you.

[image: Datasets used in the mentioned paper]

Answer (score 0):

All datasets you need is free for your research.

Yes you can download IMDB for free here:

https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/imdb-movie-reviews-dataset

and here for Yelp by registeration for free:

https://www.yelp.com/dataset/download

and yahoo dataset for free:

https://yahoo-answers-datasets.soft112.com/

and also amazon dataset for free:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-reviews-pds/readme.html

Comment: Do you have any problem to get them?